# Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity_1) with shape [1, 3087, 2] to a Java object with shape [1, 3087]

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run a YoloV4 model on Android that's been converted to .tflite. My input shape seems to be fine [1, 224, 224, 4] but the app crashes on my output shape. I'm using code from a Udacity course on tflite.

I get the above error when I run the following code:

```
class TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel private constructor() : Classifier {
override val statString: String
    get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
private var isModelQuantized: Boolean = false
// Config values.
private var inputSize: Int = 0
// Pre-allocated buffers.
private val labels = Vector<String>()
private var intValues: IntArray? = null
// outputLocations: array of shape [Batchsize, NUM_DETECTIONS,4]
// contains the location of detected boxes
private var outputLocations: Array<Array<FloatArray>>? = null
// outputClasses: array of shape [Batchsize, NUM_DETECTIONS]
// contains the classes of detected boxes
private var outputClasses: Array<FloatArray>? = null
// outputScores: array of shape [Batchsize, NUM_DETECTIONS]
// contains the scores of detected boxes
private var outputScores: Array<FloatArray>? = null
// numDetections: array of shape [Batchsize]
// contains the number of detected boxes
private var numDetections: FloatArray? = null

private var imgData: ByteBuffer? = null

private var tfLite: Interpreter? = null

override fun recognizeImage(bitmap: Bitmap): List<Classifier.Recognition> {
    // Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage")

    Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap")
    // Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
    // on the provided parameters.
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)

    imgData!!.rewind()
    for (i in 0 until inputSize) {
        for (j in 0 until inputSize) {
            val pixelValue = intValues!![i * inputSize + j]
            if (isModelQuantized) {
                // Quantized model
                imgData!!.put((pixelValue shr 16 and 0xFF).toByte())
                imgData!!.put((pixelValue shr 8 and 0xFF).toByte())
                imgData!!.put((pixelValue and 0xFF).toByte())
            } else { // Float model
                imgData!!.putFloat(((pixelValue shr 16 and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
                imgData!!.putFloat(((pixelValue shr 8 and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
                imgData!!.putFloat(((pixelValue and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
            }
        }
    }
    Trace.endSection() // preprocessBitmap

    // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
    Trace.beginSection("feed")
    outputLocations = Array(1) { Array(NUM_DETECTIONS) { FloatArray(4) } }
    outputClasses = Array(1) { FloatArray(NUM_DETECTIONS) }
    outputScores = Array(1) { FloatArray(NUM_DETECTIONS) }
    numDetections = FloatArray(1)

    val inputArray = arrayOf<Any>(imgData!!)
    val outputMap = ArrayMap<Int, Any>()
    outputMap[0] = outputLocations!!
    outputMap[1] = outputClasses!!
    outputMap[2] = outputScores!!
    outputMap[3] = numDetections!!
    Trace.endSection()

    // Run the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("run")
    tfLite!!.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap)
    Trace.endSection()

    // Show the best detections.
    // after scaling them back to the input size.
    val recognitions = ArrayList<Classifier.Recognition>(NUM_DETECTIONS)
    for (i in 0 until NUM_DETECTIONS) {
        val detection = RectF(
                outputLocations!![0][i][1] * inputSize,
                outputLocations!![0][i][0] * inputSize,
                outputLocations!![0][i][3] * inputSize,
                outputLocations!![0][i][2] * inputSize)
        // SSD Mobilenet V1 Model assumes class 0 is background class
        // in label file and class labels start from 1 to number_of_classes+1,
        // while outputClasses correspond to class index from 0 to number_of_classes
        val labelOffset = 1
        recognitions.add(
                Classifier.Recognition(
                        "" + i,
                        labels[outputClasses!![0][i].toInt() + labelOffset],
                        outputScores!![0][i],
                        detection))
    }
    Trace.endSection() // "recognizeImage"
    return recognitions
}

override fun enableStatLogging(debug: Boolean) {
    //Not implemented
}

override fun close() {
    //Not needed.
}

override fun setNumThreads(numThreads: Int) {
    if (tfLite != null) tfLite!!.setNumThreads(numThreads)
}

override fun setUseNNAPI(isChecked: Boolean) {
    if (tfLite != null) tfLite!!.setUseNNAPI(isChecked)
}

companion object {

    // Only return this many results.
    private const val NUM_DETECTIONS = 3087
    // Float model
    private const val IMAGE_MEAN = 128.0f
    private const val IMAGE_STD = 128.0f

    /** Memory-map the model file in Assets.  */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun loadModelFile(assets: AssetManager, modelFilename: String): MappedByteBuffer {
        val fileDescriptor = assets.openFd(modelFilename)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
        val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
        val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a native TensorFlow session for classifying images.
     *
     * @param assetManager The asset manager to be used to load assets.
     * @param modelFilename The filepath of the model GraphDef protocol buffer.
     * @param labelFilename The filepath of label file for classes.
     * @param inputSize The size of image input
     * @param isQuantized Boolean representing model is quantized or not
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun create(
            assetManager: AssetManager,
            modelFilename: String,
            labelFilename: String,
            inputSize: Int,
            isQuantized: Boolean): Classifier {
        val d = TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel()

        val labelsInput: InputStream?
        val actualFilename = labelFilename.split("file:///android_asset/".toRegex())
                .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()[1]
        labelsInput = assetManager.open(actualFilename)
        val br: BufferedReader?
        br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(labelsInput!!))
        while (br.readLine()?.let { d.labels.add(it) } != null);
        br.close()

        d.inputSize = inputSize

        try {
            val options = Interpreter.Options()
            options.setNumThreads(4)
            d.tfLite = Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename), options)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

        d.isModelQuantized = isQuantized
        // Pre-allocate buffers.
        val numBytesPerChannel: Int = if (isQuantized) {
            1 // Quantized
        } else {
            4 // Floating point
        }
        d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel)
        d.imgData!!.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        d.intValues = IntArray(d.inputSize * d.inputSize)

        d.outputLocations = Array(1) { Array(NUM_DETECTIONS) { FloatArray(2) } }
        d.outputClasses = Array(1) { FloatArray(NUM_DETECTIONS) }
        d.outputScores = Array(1) { FloatArray(NUM_DETECTIONS) }
        d.numDetections = FloatArray(1)
        return d
    }
}
```

When I change the outputLocation to

```
outputLocations = Array(1) { Array(NUM_DETECTIONS) { FloatArray(2) } }
```

I get the following error **Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 3087, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 3087, 2]**

What is Identity and Identity_1? I've looked at my model on Netron and can see both but I'm not sure how to understand the model.

Can anyone help? Is there anything else I can change or is my model just not suitable for mobile platforms?

Comment: Give us a link to build and debug

Answer (score 0):

Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 25200, 8] to a Java object with shape [1, 80, 80, 255].
I have encountered similar problems and haven't found a solution yet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31025515)